# Hide the second ComboBox(Collapse) on selecting a item from first Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have created User control, added `ComboBox` in it as `View1`.

View1:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="XYZ.Views.ComboBoxView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource textControlText}" Text="{Binding Label}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Value}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Ui" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Visibility="{Binding Visible}">
            <ComboBox.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Help}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="400"/>
                </ToolTip>
            </ComboBox.ToolTip>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and i have corresponding `View1Model` with `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`,  `ObservableCollection` of list items and `Visible` property.

View1Model:-

```
class XyZComboBoxViewModel
{

    private ObservableCollection<XyZListItem> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<XyZListItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }

    private XyZListItem _selectedItem;

    public XyZListItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { 
           some code here          
        }
    }

    private Enum _visible;

   public Enum Visibile
   {
    get{return _visible}
    set{return _visible=value //passing System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;}
    }

    private int _selectedIndex;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set { _selectedIndex = value; }
    }
  }
```

I have another `View2` and `View2Model`.

In `View2Model` I create Two `View1model` objects(i.e 2 ComboBox's) and bind it to second view `View2`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsTabStop="False"  />
```

The Two ComboBox's(List Box User control's) getting displayed in the `View2`.

Now i want to hide the second `ComboBox`(with Visibility set to Collapsed) on selecting a item from the first `ComboBox`.

On Selecting an item from first `ComboBox`, I iterate over the View1Model objects in `View2Model` and setting the Second `ComboBox` Visible property value to `Visibility.Collapsed`.

The problem is I'm not able to hide the  second `ComboBox`.

Please help me.

Comment: Please be aware that your accepted answer is not how this task is normally achieved in WPF. It is far more usual to have a `bool` property data bound to the control's `Visibility` property using the [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the `bool` value into a `Visibility` value. Therefore, setting the `bool` value to false will hide the control and setting it to `true` will show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the mentioned code.

```
 private Visibility _comboboxvisibility;

   public Visibility comboboxvisibility
   {
       get { return _comboboxvisibility; }
       set { _comboboxvisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged("comboboxvisibility"); }
   }

   private XyZListItem _selectedItem;

   public XyZListItem SelectedItem
   {
       get { return _selectedItem; }
       set {
           comboboxvisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;         
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void UpdateAttributes(ComboBox sender)
    {
        var definitions = _attributeDefinitions.ToList();

        {
            var combobox = cmbAttributeDefinition1;

            if (sender != combobox && combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                definitions.RemoveAll(
                    x => x.AttrID == (imProfileAttributeID)combobox.SelectedValue);
        }

        {
            var combobox = cmbAttributeDefinition2;

            if (sender != combobox && combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                definitions.RemoveAll(
                    x => x.AttrID == (imProfileAttributeID)combobox.SelectedValue);
        }

        {
            var combobox = cmbAttributeDefinition3;

            if (sender != combobox && combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                definitions.RemoveAll(
                    x => x.AttrID == (imProfileAttributeID)combobox.SelectedValue);
        }

        {
            var combobox = cmbAttributeDefinition4;

            if (sender != combobox && combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                definitions.RemoveAll(
                    x => x.AttrID == (imProfileAttributeID)combobox.SelectedValue);
        }


        {
            var combobox = cmbAttributeDefinition5;

            if (sender != combobox && combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                definitions.RemoveAll(
                    x => x.AttrID == (imProfileAttributeID)combobox.SelectedValue);
        }


        sender.DataSource = definitions;
        sender.DisplayMember = "Caption";
        sender.ValueMember = "AttrID";
    }

  private void cmbAttributeDefinition1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAttributes(sender as ComboBox);
    }

    private void cmbAttributeDefinition5_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAttributes(sender as ComboBox);
    }

    private void cmbAttributeDefinition2_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAttributes(sender as ComboBox);
    }

    private void cmbAttributeDefinition3_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAttributes(sender as ComboBox);
    }

    private void cmbAttributeDefinition4_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAttributes(sender as ComboBox);
    }
```